# How to select max value based on multiple fields and grouped by multiple fields

Tags: sql, group-by, max, multiple-columns

please assist with the following.
Sample Data:

```
LOCATION    ITEMNO  TRANSDATE   DAYENDSEQ   ENTRYSEQ    LINENO  ANSWER
Area1       A       20180702    1           1           1       a
Area1       A       20180703    1           1           1       b
Area1       A       20180703    2           1           1       c
Area1       A       20180703    2           2           1       d
Area1       A       20180703    2           2           2       e
Area1       B       20180703    1           1           1       f
Area1       C       20180703    1           1           2       g
Area1       C       20180703    1           1           1       h
Area2       A       20180703    1           2           1       i
Area2       A       20180703    1           1           4       j
Area2       A       20180703    1           1           5       k
```

To return the ANSWER value for each Item per Location where the combination of TRANSDATE, DAYENDSEQ, ENTRYSEQ and LINENO (in this order) is the largest.

```
LOCATION    ITEMNO  TRANSDATE   DAYENDSEQ   ENTRYSEQ    LINENO  ANSWER
Area1       A       20180703    2           2           2       e
Area1       B       20180703    1           1           1       f
Area1       C       20180703    1           1           2       g
Area2       A       20180703    1           2           1       i
```

Comment: Tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: What do you mean by combination is the "largest"

Comment: Per @TimBiegeleisen's comment; do you mean if you summed all those values together; or do you mean the first record if you were to sort by each of those fields in descending order; so if you have several records are on the same max transdate, within that subset you then look for the max dayendseq; then entryseq, and so on until you've found the top result; or do you mean something else?

Comment: The largest meaning if you were to sort by each of those fields in descending order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ANSI-standard `row_number()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by location, itemno 
                                order by transdate desc, dayendseq desc, entryseq desc, lineno desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just added ITEMNO to the partition to look over each item per location.